# Easy way to view postgresql dump files?

Tags: database, postgresql-9.1, pg-dump

I have a ton of postgresql dump files I need to peruse through for data. Do I have to install Postgresql and "recover" each one of them into new databases one by one? Or I'm hoping there's a postgresql client that can simply open them up and I can peek at the data, maybe even run a simple SQL query?

The dump files are all from a Postgresql v9.1.9 server.

Or maybe there's a tool that can easily make a database "connection" to the dump files?

***UPDATE***: These are **not text files**. They are **binary**. They come from Heroku's backup mechanism, this is [what Heroku says about how they create their backups](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export):

> PG Backups uses the native pg_dump PostgreSQL tool to create its
>   backup files, making it trivial to export to other PostgreSQL
>   installations.

Comment: how were the dumps made? i.e. ... do you have the exact command used to create them?

Comment: Dumps were made from Heroku's backup mechanism

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try opening the files with text editor - the default dump format is plain text.

If the dump is not plain text - try using `pg_restore -l your_db_dump.file` command. It will list all objects in the database dump (like tables, indexes ...).

Another possible way (may not work, haven't tried it) is to `grep` through the output of `pg_restore your_db_dump.file` command. If I understood correctly the manual - the output of `pg_restore` is just a sequence of SQL queries, that will rebuild the db.

Comment: is `pg_restore` a command that's installed when installing the Postgresql server? Or can I easily grab that command from somewhere?

Comment: `pg_restore -l` only gives you the tables and other metadata, not the actual data. Your last suggestion worked perfect for me, however.

Answer (score 78):

This was what I was looking for:

```
pg_restore db.bin > db.sql
```

Thanks @andrewtweber

Comment: The dump file might be large. If that is the case, I suggest you to try `pg_restore db.bin | less`, if you only want to take a look or execute `pg_restore db.bin | psql dbname > log 2> error` if you want to restore it.

Comment: Now what? `pg_restore: [archiver] unsupported version (1.13) in file header`

Comment: @Chloe that means that your `pg_restore` version is too low for the backup you're trying to restore.

Comment: With Postgres 13, I had to do `pg_restore db.bin -f db.sql` instead, see also @AlexDev's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59378860/715870)

Answer (score 29):

In newer versions you need to specify the `-f` flag with a filename or '-' for stdout

```
pg_restore -f - dump_file.bin
```

Comment: Thank you! I was having trouble with the above solutions.

Comment: So in other words in order to   generate a file with raw sql `pg_restore dump_file.bin -f  dump_file.sql`   Thank you for this

Comment: the syntax is incorrect, it should be: `pg_restore -f extracted.sql dump_file.bin` options have to go before specifying dump file

Comment: @Mihailo, we need your comment higher up. I hope the moderators edit this answer.

Comment: @Mihailo I updated the answer according to the comments, although I didn't test it

Comment: @Mihailo In my version of `pg_restore` the options can also come after.

Answer (score 15):

I had this same problem and I ended up doing this:

1. Install Postgresql and PGAdmin3.
2. Open PGAdmin3 and create a database.
3. Right click the db and click restore.
4. Ignore file type.
5. Select the database dump file from Heroku.
6. Click Restore.

Answer (score 3):

```
pg_restore -f - db.bin > db.sql
```

Comment: `-f - ... > foo` is, more simply, `-f foo ...`.  See AlexDev's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Dump files are usually text file, if Not compressed, and you can open them with a text editor. Inside you will find all the queries that allow the reconstruction of the database ...

Comment: These dumps are not text files, they're binary

Answer (score 0):

If you use pgAdmin on Windows, can just backup the file as plain text, there is one option when you do backup instead of pg_dump in command line prompt.